# best way of counting number of rows for each grouped by column

Tags: python, pandas

after grouping by two columns df.groupby(["id","b"]) 
now I want to find "id" where there are more than 5 rows.

so in the df below,

id = 4 has 2 rows
id = 4 has 3 rows.

```
                count   
id          b           
4         1568    1 
          4167    1 
5         1100    1 
          1832    2 
          1969    5
```

I've simply reset_index()

and got id values on each row then added them.

Comment: Where does that DataFrame come from? Is that the concatenated result of the `groupby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
rows = df.groupby("id")["b"].apply(lambda x: len(list(x)))
```

output

```
id
4    2
5    3
```

Comment: Won’t the `x` here be a Series?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(level=0).size()
```

Comment: I hope OP sees your answer, it’s far better.